# How to increase the size of the coloured rectangle height from top to bottom ,[css]?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the colored rectangle from top to bottom (in the black box).
How to increase its height don't want to give the custom heights to the small colored rectangle in the black box, what needs to be done is to set the height in such a way that colored rectangle should always fit the black box as sidebar no matter how big or small the black box is.

[image]

The colored rectangle in the black box has the div with id as a circle

Comment: Your need to provide a demo of your existing code. Sharing image is least helpful without accompanying code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the black box has position relative, you can change the orange boxs position to absolute, and then specify that it needs to be from top 0px, and from bottom 0px
so

```
black-box {
    position: relative;
}

orange-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add **height:100%;** to orange box that will changed automatically when blackbox size changed

Answer (score 0):

**I think the following code will solve your problem**

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.item{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```